# != and multiple queries in where clause mysql php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$update = "UPDATE masterlist SET activity = :active WHERE year = :year;"
          ."UPDATE masterlist SET activity = :inactive WHERE year != :year;";
```

I have the code above to update my database but unfortunately it is not happening they way I want it happen.

Example

In my database I have column named `year` which has year values and a clomun named activity which has value either `active` or `inactive`.

1. If `year - 2002` = `activity - active`
2. I want to do is Update `year - 2015` = `activity - active`
3. The `rest of the activity should be inactive`except year 2015

What is happening is all the activity is change to `active`

1. How to do multiple queries is php pdo.
2. How to `not equal to` in ***WHERE*** clause

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're asking. So you would like activity to be `active` for all the records with value 2002 or 2015 in the `year` column and have the rest holding `inactive`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you can run [multiple queries in PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#multiquery), by means of turning emulation mode `ON`, there is not a single reason to do so.

Just run your queries in two separate calls.

And regarding `!=` - it's all right to use it in MySQL.

Comment: I see so i didnt know about turning emulation mode that is probobly the reason why it didnt run. Then the problem really is not with the WHERE clause the problem is that the second update didnt run at all. let me check if i do two separate calls.

Comment: thank you for pointing me to the right direction. and for the link on multiple hope the link wont rot although i dont have time to read it now i will definitely need it someday.